# Entry linking meta data

Tags: entry, next-prev

Just wondering if it is possible to show the `{author}`, `{entry_date}` and `{comment_total}` in the Prev/Next entry links? Here is what I have currently for the Next entry link, but only the `{title}` field is working—

```
{exp:channel:next_entry channel="news"}
      <div class="element clearfix col1-3 home grey">
        <a href="{path='news/index'}" title="" class="whole-tile">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
          <p class="small"><span class="italic">by</span> {author} <br />
            <span class="italic">posted</span> {entry_date:relative}<br />
          <span class="italic">with</span> {comment_total} Comments</p>

          <div class="bottom">
            <p class="alignleft">Read more</p>
          <span class="arrow">→</span></div>
        </a> 
      </div>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those single variables are not available in that tag (exp:channel:next_entry). It would be somewhat inefficient, but you could run a template embed to achieve this. This would be the code in your main template:

```
{exp:channel:next_entry channel="news"}
    <div class="element clearfix col1-3 home grey">
        <a href="{path='news/index'}" title="" class="whole-tile">
            <h3>
                {title}
            </h3>
            {embed="embeds/next_entry" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        </a> 
    </div>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

And this would be the code in your embeds/next_entry template:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <p class="small">
        <span class="italic">
            by
        </span>
        {author} <br />
        <span class="italic">
            posted
        </span>
        {entry_date} <br />
        <span class="italic">
            with
        </span>
        {comment_total} Comments
    </p>
    <div class="bottom">
        <p class="alignleft">
            Read more
        </p>
        <span class="arrow">
            →
        </span> 
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: You're a superstar, thank you very much :)

Comment: Test it out, and if it works (you can comment back if you run into issues, always glad to help), please accept my answer as correct! Thanks!